# How to avoid creating an instance of a base class when using prototype inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, prototypal-inheritance

When using prototype-inheritance in Javascript, we have to create at some point an instance of the base class simply to insert its prototype in the calling chain. For example if I have a class A and a class B that inherits from A., it looks like that:

```
function A() {}

function B() {}

B.prototype = new A();
```

This is very annoying because I don't want to create an A yet and this can have negative side effects. How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: "…and this can have negative side effects", such as?

Comment: Why don't you want to create `A`? Do you have an issue with using an Object literal instead?

Comment: @PHPglue–you can't do prototype inheritance with literals, you must either use a constructor or [*Object.create*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5) to assign to an object's `[[Prototype]]` (ignoring [*setPrototypeOf*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.setprototypeof) in ES6 draft and non–standard [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property).

Comment: I don't create A because it has nothing to do with creating a derived class. In what language are you force to create an instance to create a derived class?

Comment: @PierreThibault–ECMAScript. Your solution just replaces creating instances of *A* with creating instances of *deco*. What problem are you trying to solve that *Object.create* doesn't?

Comment: It seems Object.create solve the problem that I had. It didn't know about it.

Comment: Why don't you put the `Object.create()` solution in the answer you wrote.  That is the better way to create the desired prototype object to inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

I created two functions to avoid these side effects:

```
function constructor(func) {
    function deco() {
        if(arguments.callee.caller && arguments.callee.caller === setParent) {
            return;
        }
        return func.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return deco;
}

function setParent(construcFunc, base) {
    construcFunc.prototype = new base();     
    construcFunc.prototype.constructor = construcFunc;   
}
```

Now I can define my classes:

```
var A = constructor(function() {});
var B = constructor(function() {});
setParent(B, A);
```

Here `constructor` is a decorator function. Its purpose is do nothing when a object is created by a call from `setParent` so the side effects that may occur are avoided. Done.

Comment: You don't have to re-invent a solution. This is a long-standing problem in JavaScript inheritance, solved in the ECMAScript standard directly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: Note that [*arguments.callee*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) is not available in strict mode, and [*callee.caller*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) was not standardised and has been deprecated in browsers that use it.

Comment: OK, I didn't know. It did try to find a solution by it was not easy to phrase in a Google search.

Answer (score 0):

Seem that `Object.create`, has proposed by some of you, does just that. [Object.create() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)